# Metadata filtering for a listview webpart

Tags: web-part, pages, sharepoint-list-filter

Followed tutorials [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8s3SK-BYZeM) to turn on list metadata filtering. Most of the tutorials I'm finding are form more recent versions of SP, but it worked in our SP 2013 as well.

When we have the list view aspx page we get the metadata filtering. (We've uses some jQuery to move it around and adjust some other parts of the page, but it looks more or less like this.

[image]

The challenge is we don't want the end user to go to the listview aspx page. We want them to go to a publishing page with a listview webpart.

But when we add the listview webpart to the page we don't get the metadata filtering part. Is there a way to add that on a publishing page when using a listview webpart?

I tried using the filtering webparts, but they don't include the Role and Workstream columns (managed metadata columns).

Searching finds lots of tutorials on how to turn it on, but doesn't mention putting it on publishing pages. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a built-in way to do that, but more than one person has created a [custom webpart](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/20/sharepoint-metadata-filter-page-web-parts/) to do it.